# integration of a concave function

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

I'm having some trouble with the following question:

> let $ f: [0,2]\to \Bbb R$ be a continuous nonnegative function. It is also given that $f$ is concave ($\cap$)
>    that is for each two points $x,y\in[0,2]$ and $\lambda\in[0,1]$ sustain 
>   $$f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)\ge\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)$$
>   Lets assume that $f(1)=1$, prove that $$\int_0^2f(t)dt\ge1$$

I tried finding a linear function that this integral is greater than (thought about $X$ for example) but I didnt get any further than that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f(1)=1$, then by concavity, for every $\lambda\in[0,1]$, 
$$f(0\lambda+1(1-\lambda))\geq\lambda f(0)+(1-\lambda)f(1)$$
Since $f$ is non-negative, $f(0)\geq0$ and
$$f(0\lambda+1(1-\lambda))\geq\lambda f(0)+(1-\lambda)f(1)\geq \lambda 0+(1-\lambda)f(1)$$
Since $f(1)=1$, the previous could be written as
$$f(1-\lambda) \geq1-\lambda$$
So for every $x\in[0,1]$, 
$$f(x)\geq x$$
Now we do the same for $[1,2]$. Since $f$ is non-negative, $f(2)\geq0$ and
$$f(1\lambda+2(1-\lambda))\geq\lambda f(1)+(1-\lambda)f(2)\geq\lambda f(1)$$
$$f(2-\lambda)\geq\lambda$$
So, for $x\in[1,2]$
$$f(x)\geq2-x$$
The function is greater than the triangle whose vertex are at $(0,0)$, $(2,0)$ and $(1,1)$. The integral will be greater than the area of this triangle. This trangle has a basis of length $2$ and a height of $1$, then an area of $1$.

We could also do it by integral
$$\int_0^2 f(x)dx\geq \int_0^1xdx +\int_1^2(2-x)dx=\frac12+\frac12=1$$

Comment: thank you so much it was very helpful! a quick question -you got here  $f(x)≥2−x$ by saying $x=2-\lambda$  ?